# Proposition of $\ln$ Function

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that $\ln(x^r)=r\ln(x)$.

Proof. Comparing derivatives, we see that

$$\dfrac {d(\ln(x^r))}{dx}=\dfrac {rx^{r-1}}{x^r}=\dfrac {r}{x}=\dfrac {d(r\ln(x))}{dx}.$$

Hence $\ln(x^r)=r\ln(x) +C$ for any $x>0$ and any rational number $r$.
Letting $x=1$ we get $C=0$ and the result holds.

**My question is** the proof is for rational number $r$, so is the proof true for real numbers $r$?

Comment: @BillO'Haran Yes, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By definition for $x>0$ and $r\in\mathbb R$:$$e^{\ln(x^r)}\stackrel{1}{=} x^r\stackrel{2}{=} (e^{\ln x})^r\stackrel{3}{=}e^{r\ln x}$$so that: $$\ln x^r=r\ln x$$

Comment: How did you pass from $3$ to $e^{r\ln(x)}$? What did you use this?

Comment: @Kahler For some reason, this user decided to post a different proof. He's using the definition of $\ln(x)$ as the inverse of the exponential function. Some textbooks define $\ln(x)$ as $\int_1^x\frac{1}{y}dy$, in which case your proof is more appropriate -- and works in general.